# Spring Data @DomainEvents with AbstractAggregateRoot fails for save(List<S> iterables)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, domain-driven-design

Spring Data's `@DomainEvents` with `AbstractAggregateRoot` work great but fails for `repository.save(Iterable<S> entities)` on the domain object it is used on.

The error trace is as below :-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:201)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.EventPublishingRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$EventPublishingMethod.publishEventsFrom(EventPublishingRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:173)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.EventPublishingRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$EventPublishingMethodInterceptor.invoke(EventPublishingRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.
```

The issue is cause the `clearDomainEvents(…)` is being applied in the above case as per the code below in `EventPublishingRepositoryProxyPostProcessor`

```
    if (clearingMethod != null) {
        ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(clearingMethod, object);
    }
```

Will be great if this can be resolved or am I missing something here.

Comment: did you try debugging??

Comment: yup tried it tries to invoke the clearDomainEvents method on the Object which in case of save(iterables) is a list , for publishing events it's handled but for clearDomainEvents as well it should put the logic .

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you get this exception even if your event handling code is empty? If this is the case, please file a bug.

Comment: can you show your clear method.

Comment: @MathiasDpunkt For this entity I do not have a clear method , the one involved is from the spring data AbstractAggregateRoot class which my entity class extends.Also I do not call the register event method in the case.

Comment: created https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1178

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be running into [DATACMNS-1067](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1067), which has been fixed with the Ingalls SR4 release train. Please make sure to upgrade to this or (recommended) to the latest version, currently Ingalls SR7.

Comment: Hi Oliver a follow up question  I have seen concurrent modification exceptions coming if say events are are fired in a nested fashion .
Example
Event 1 Fired on Domain -> 
Event 1 captured by Listener -> 
Event 2 Fired inside listener on same domain object
All the above taking place in a multi threaded setup .Should a conncurrent CopyOnwrite arraylist be used instead.